# Where is the text file once I publish the program?

Tags: c#, text, streamwriter

I made a program that takes user input from a text box and writes it to a text file when a button is pressed.  When I finally published it, I wasn't able to find the text files anywhere.  Here's the code:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw1 = new StreamWriter("DataNames.txt",true))
        {
            sw1.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
        }
```

Where is the file, or how can I make it write to a certain place?

Comment: is this web application? where you want to save files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using (StreamWriter sw1 = new StreamWriter(@"c:\someFolder\DataNames.txt",true))
```

or

```
using (StreamWriter sw1 = new StreamWriter("c:\\someFolder\\DataNames.txt",true))
```

Just give it the full path you want to use. Use @ to escape the \ char. Or you can specify `\` as `\\`

If you don't specify a directory it will go in the bin folder (where the .exe is)

Comment: Technicly it goes in the working directory, some things like the OpenFileDialog or SaveFileDialog will change the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

> Where is the file?

it will be created on where your exe or dlls located.

> how can I make it write to a certain place?

you can give full path to file location

```
using (StreamWriter sw1 = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(DirectoryPath, "DataNames.txt"),true))
{
    sw1.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
}
```

Comment: How would I write a full path for it using streamwriter?

Comment: @BrendanByers give `DirectoryPath` as the path to folder where you want to save files

Answer (score 0):

Write to certain place as below. Please have a look at [How to: Write to a Text File (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8bh11f1k.aspx) too.

```
        // Example #3: Write only some strings in an array to a file. 
        // The using statement automatically closes the stream and calls  
        // IDisposable.Dispose on the stream object. 
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines2.txt"))
        {
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                // If the line doesn't contain the word 'Second', write the line to the file. 
                if (!line.Contains("Second"))
                {
                    file.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
        }
```